# Multiple $near in mongo 2.6.4 does not work

Tags: json, mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query

I have collection with document like this:

```
{
  ...
  "CurrentLocation" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        -92.48436693078111, 
        35.85223020932276
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

And I need to make a "$near" query with two possible center points:

```
db.Truck.find({
    "$or": [{
        "DestinationLocation": {
            "$near": {
                "$geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [-117.256875, 41.856405]
                },
                "$maxDistance": 100000.0
            }
        }
    }, {
        "DestinationLocation": {
            "$near": {
                "$geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [-112.256875, 40.856405]
                },
                "$maxDistance": 100000.0
            }
        }
    }]
})
```

**Mongo returns me an error:**

```
error:
{
"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Too many geoNear expressions",
"code" : 17287
}
```

Is there any way to request $near with two points except data union on the application side? 
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is now my question. I read [anhlc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26330503/8784518)  answer, But I am wondering if there is another easier and more efficient way to receive the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongo DB accepts only one NEAR. And if there is a NEAR, it must be either the root or the root
must be an AND and its child must be a NEAR. See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/query/canonical_query.cpp#L364

If you need that `$or` operation with two `$near`, try to make two queries and integrate the results from them.

Comment: Could you provide an example for your suggestion?

Comment: @anhlc Are you sure that I have to write multiple queries? and there is no other solution?

Comment: @KasirBarati, yes, it's still a restriction in latest mongodb version: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/query/canonical_query.cpp#L364

Answer (score -1):

**An example with $or**

```
db.Truck.find({
    "DestinationLocation": {
        "$or":[{
          "$near": {
              "$geometry": {
                  "type": "Point",
                  "coordinates": [-117.256875, 41.856405]
              },
              "$maxDistance": 100000.0
            }
        },{
        "$near": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-112.256875, 40.856405]
            },
            "$maxDistance": 100000.0
          }
        }]

    }

})
```

Comment: Hi @gsa, How you write such a query. It will throw an error. I try to do the same thing but I get the same error as explained in the question. :(